# two async tasks - one depends on another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I need to write a code where i need to to check in real time a status of some variable. I decited to use `asyncio` to create two async def functions

```
import asyncio

async def one():
    global flag
    flag = True
    while flag == True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print("Doing one")

async def two():
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    global flag
    flag = False

async def main():
    tasks = []
    tasks.append(one())
    tasks.append(two())
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
finally:
    loop.close()
    print("Loop ended")
```

When loop starts, all tasks has been lauched and after 2 seconds `def two()` sets `flag=False`, which stops `def one()`. It's good but i want `def one()` to perform while loop without `await asyncio.sleep(0.2)` becouse i dont want to have real live update so i set `await asyncio.sleep(0.0)`.
Is it a good practice?

Comment: When you say "It's good but i want def one() to perform while loop without await `asyncio.sleep(0.2)` becouse i dont want to have real live update so i set await `asyncio.sleep(0.0)`", what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a global variable is indeed bad practice. What you are looking for is `asyncio`'s primitives, specifically the [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event) primitive. Here is what you are doing, but with `asyncio.Event`:

```py
import asyncio

async def one(event):
    while event.is_set() == False:
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        print("Hello World!")

async def two(event):
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    event.set()

async def main():
    event = asyncio.Event()
    await asyncio.gather(*[one(event), two(event)])

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Felipe, fine but can we set no delay inside while loop in `def one(event)`? example: `await asyncio.sleep(0.0)`?

Comment: This sounds like a possible [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Let me ask you: why do you need the `while` loop?